# Blender 2.8 No compatible GPUs found for path tracing

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu

I was having this problem where my blender 2.8 didn't recognize my GPU driver.

I have a AMD RX 580 and my operating system is Ubuntu 18.04. For those who have this same problem I will post it as an answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you have to download and install the AMD pro drivers for your GPU [here](https://www.amd.com/en/support).

If you're using Linux you just extract it and open the terminal inside the folder you just extracted. Type in the terminal `./amdgpu-pro-install  --opencl=pal,legacy,rocm` and hit enter. It is very important to put the opencl options. That was the reason why I was trying to install and reinstall my GPU drivers and nothing happened.

Restart your pc and check your GPU options in blender.

I hope this helps all Linux users facing this problem.

Found this solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1189626/cannot-get-opencl-to-work-with-radeon-5700xt).

[image]